# How to use a discrete distribution as a class variable in C++

Tags: c++, header, distribution

So I have a huge program (several .cpp files and .h) developed by someone else and I am trying to add some functionalities in just one of such files. I am new to C++ so it is hard for me.

I want to use initialise a power-law distribution when initialising an "optimizer" and later sample from it when calling an "iteration". I have manage to make it work but only inside the "inisialisation" and I want it to work in the whole file as a class variable. A minimum example of what I want is as follows, taking into account that Optimizer is defined in "Optimizer.h" and is not really relevant and the random engine is defined in "Util.h".

The header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef FASTONEPLUSONE_H_
#define FASTONEPLUSONE_H_

#include "Optimizer.h"
#include "Util.h"
#include <map>

// Inherits and implements the Optimizer interface
class FastOnePlusOne : public Optimizer {
 public:
  FastOnePlusOne(Random& _rand, shared_ptr<Evaluator> _evaluator,
               Configuration& _config);
  virtual bool iterate() override;
  create_optimizer(FastOnePlusOne);

 private:
  // Power law distribution
  std::discrete_distribution<int>power_dist; // THIS IS MADE BY ME
};

#endif /* FASTONEPLUSONE_H_ */
```

And the cpp file:

```
FastOnePlusOne::FastOnePlusOne(Random& _rand, shared_ptr<Evaluator> _evaluator,
                           Configuration& _config)
    : Optimizer(_rand, _evaluator, _config) {
  // Power-law distribution
  int length = 10;
  float B = 1.5;
  vector<double> pmf(length);
  std::iota(pmf.begin(), pmf.end(), 1);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    pmf[i] = 1.0 / pow(pmf[i], B);
  }
  pmf.insert(pmf.begin(), 0);
  std::discrete_distribution<int> power_dist(pmf.begin(),pmf.end());
  
  std::map<int, int> m;
  for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
    ++m[power_dist(rand)];
  }
  for(auto p : m) {
    std::cout << p.first << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
  }
}

// Performs an iteration
bool FastOnePlusOne::iterate() {
  // Distributions needed at the current alpha
  int alpha = power_dist(rand);
  std::cout << alpha << " ";
  }
}
```

This code right now creates the power law distribution in the variable power_dist when `FastOnePlusOne` is initialized and it prints the results of 10000 samples correctly, but `alpha` is always sampled as 0. How can I fix this?

Comment: Thank you for your input, do you have any suggestion on how to reorganize it? and why the title has no relation, I thought the variables in the header file are considered global in the file

Comment: It is not a global variable, it is a class variable. And the problem has little to bo with discrete distribution, but instead with lack of proper initialization.

Comment: ok thank you, I will edit the title in case someone else is having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
std::discrete_distribution<int> power_dist(pmf.begin(),pmf.end());
```

with this:

```
power_dist = std::discrete_distribution<int>(pmf.begin(),pmf.end());
```

Explanation:

In the wrong version, you are creating a new local variable called `power_dist` who shadows the class variable `this->power_dist`, and using it. Original `this->power_dist` is never used or properly initialized inside `FastOnePlusOne::FastOnePlusOne()`. In function `FastOnePlusOne::iterate()` you sample the uninitialized `this->power_dist`.

In the second version, you would assign a properly initialized object to the class variable `power_dist`, who is used later in the same function and also in the `iterate()` function.